# ASP.NET core 2.1 Database-Migration

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have following PROJECT structures.

[image: PROJECT STRUCTURES]

While adding Migration, it does not recognize my Project"Ravangla.WebUI" directory, which is not in the same directory

[image: Ravangla WebUI]

My Add-Migration command as follow:-

```
Add-Migration initial -context RavanglaDbContext -p Ravangla.Persistence
```

Error:-

```
The directory name 'C:\Ravangla.Client\Ravangla..WebUI\' does not exist.
Parameter name: path
```

It does not show correct path first of all as you can notice above: "Ravangla..WebUI", it has two [..], which is not true.

[image]